# What preferred dns IP address set to my dns server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I have setup only one(for now) DNS Server on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 system. The computer network adapter has the IP address for example 190.190.190.1 ... The question is, what Preferred and Alternate IP address must to set to network adapter?

must be

```
IP Address: 190.190.190.1
Preferred DNS Server: 190.190.190.1
Alternate DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
```

or must be

```
IP Address: 190.190.190.1
Preferred DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
Alternate DNS Server: nothing
```

o something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear to me if you are asking about the DNS server itself or other clients on the network.

The DNS server should be pointing at 127.0.0.1, and you should setup forwarders within the DNS server, if you want queries to be handled by some other recursive server, instead of recursively resolving requests directly.

If you have an AD setup then your clients should only be configured to point at DNS servers with the AD-integrated DNS zone for your domain.   Ideally you should have multiple domain controllers.  If you have an AD, and you include some other external DNS server on clients in addition to your AD DNS server you will have lots of DNS issues.

Comment: Thanks you have right! Here I don't use Active Directory and that is why I asked this question.

Comment: If you aren't using AD, then it probably doesn't matter all that much.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your own caching/recursive DNS servers (2 at least). This will use the primary DNS servers for each domain if the cache is cold. The reasons are for security, speed and for reliability.

Comment: Yes! the second DNS Server I will set up later. If my isp gives me another blog IPs in different C Class. But for now I don't know what settings it's correct ... I'm stack :)